# NHibernate determine key properties

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to make a generic DataTransfer between a Firebird and a MSSQL DB.
Both Business-Libs contain the "same" classes wihch contain properties with an identical name.

My problem is, when I have a mapping with a composite key I don't know how much or which properties build the id.

So with a single ID it's easy, it's always the first property in my mapping files.

But what if I have a composite id?
I would have to identify the properties which build the key.

I thought that could be done through de hbm.xml File but I'm not sure if that would work.

How I could determine which Properties build the key at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the configuration you can ask each class for its identifyer property

```
foreach(var clazz in config.ClassMappings)
{
    var idProperties = clazz.IdentifierMapper.PropertyIterator
}
```

alternativly if you only want to query if the object already exists (and the entitytype could be only known at runtime)

```
var classMetadata = sessionfactory.GetClassMetadata(obj.GetType());
object id;
if (classMetadata.IdentifierType.IsComponentType)
    id = obj;
else
    id = classMetadata.GetIdentifier(obj, NHibernate.EntityMode.Poco);

fromDatabase = session.Get(classMetadata.EntityName, obj);
if (fromDatabase != null)
    // already exists
```

Comment: But I've got a another question.
When I'm not wrong the Get Function always takes two parameters.
The entity Type and an Identifier for the object. Right ?

Comment: if you know the type of obj on compiletime you can use the generic version, otherwise the first parameter is the entityname, i will edit